# Why can I declare a static field again inside the main() successfully in Java?

Tags: java, static, field

I declared a `private static double fd` and then I declared `double fd` again inside the main(). Why can I compile and run it successfully?

```
    public class HelloWorld {
    private static double fd = 1.0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(fd); //1.0
        double fd = 2.0;
        System.out.println(fd); //2.0


    }
}
```

Comment: you are not. you are declaring a local variable which happens to have the same name as your static variable

Comment: And just for fun and confusion, you can declare the local `fd` with a different type to the static `fd`. *And* for even more fun, you can use `fd` in its own initializer: `double fd = fd = 2.0;`.

Comment: The answer is: because the Java designers chose to make that possible.

Comment: @JBNizet, now that you've brought it up, I see you are right. I believe it is a legacy from C/C++ but they could have just easily decided to make this a compiler error. So , given the questioned usefulness vs error prone-ability of this "feature", why indeed was it decided to design the specs in this way?

Comment: Because it's extremely useful, for example to be able to do things like `this.name = name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a syntax error (although it will probably result in a logic error, a bug). The compiler will compile this code without complaint. The second declaration of     double fd  creates a local variable for the main method. The scope of this variable starts with its declaration and ends at the end of the block (as with all local variables). So the next statement uses the local variable, not the instance variable.

The local variable will no longer hold a value after the method has returned. The instance variable will not have been changed.

Hint:   Think of statements as looking "upward" from their own location to find each of their variables. They can look outside of their "glass box" in any direction if they fail to find a variable inside their own method.

It is almost always a mistake to use the same name for an instance variable and for a local variable. But it is not a syntax error, so the compiler will not warn you.

Comment: like @JB Nizet wrote: it's a design decision by the creators of the language. the compiler *could* have produce an error because of this. and given the questioned usefulness vs error prone-ability of this "feature", may it should have?

Answer (score 1):

From JLS [Scope of a Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) section:

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is not shadowed.

From JLS [Shadowing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) section:

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another
>   declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be
>   used to refer to the declared entity.

This means that you cannot use simple name (`df`) to refer class level `df` variable, because of it's shadowed by local `df` variable. But there are still two variables and you can use static variable with class name:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(fd); //1.0

    double fd = 2.0;

    System.out.println(fd); //2.0
    System.out.println(HelloWorld.fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable **fd** is function scoped, think it like, the compiler first check the scope nearest to it, and then if it dosent find there it  tries  to check the global scope, if it found something in local scope, it will print that, or else moves on to check other scope.